# Square Root Function Confusion (Python)

Tags: python

I have been doing code wars and stumbled upon a kata that requires a function that checks if a number is a perfect square. But after implementing my code. I have been returned an unexpected value and I cannot get my head around it to understand what is causing this.

Current Code:

```
import math
def is_square(n):
    if n == -abs(n):
        return False
    elif math.sqrt(n) != int(math.sqrt(n)):
        print("NOT PERFECT")
        return False
    else:
        print("PERFECT")
        return True
```

Results (Codewars):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n32H.png)
0 is being represented as "n" in the code block above.

I had tried to confirm that the elif statement on line 5 does actuactually return True by testing it on another Python Server.

```
import math
def test_function(x):
    if math.sqrt(x) != int(math.sqrt(x)):
        return False
    else:
        return True

print(test_function(0))
```

This time this code block returned True.

By this logic, I had expected my original block of code to accept 0 as a perfect square and return True but returns False instead. I would love to have a explanation on how this is happening.

Comment: `0 == -abs(0)`. Is that supposed to check for negative numbers? In that case you want `n < 0`.

Comment: Thanks, guys, I really should have spotted that kind of simplicity...

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and see [ask] for tips like how to write a good title and making a [mre], which can help catch basic mistakes like this. You might also want to learn [How to step through Python code to help debug issues](/q/4929251/4518341).

Answer (score 1):

The key is this line:

```py
if n == -abs(n):
    return False
```

Because 0 is equal to -0, this if statement causes the program to return False.

Answer (score 1):

If the input is 0, the first condition `n == -abs(n)` is true, and your function returns false before you even have the chance to reach the second condition. You don't need this weird `n == -abs(n)` anyway, it is equivalent to `n <= 0` and you should just write `n < 0` instead.